Calculate CDS spread from EOD price using Quantlib
On the ICE website it provides EOD CDS prices:
https://www.ice.com/cds-settlement-prices/icc/index-instruments
This is great, as it can be difficult to find CDS data, however CDS are typically quoted using a spread notation, rather than price (with some exceptions of course), therefore I need to back out the spread from the price.
I have tried using Quantlib to back out the spread, however it either returns an incredibly high value (which looks implausible) or a NaN.
Here are my functions (the indents are correct, not sure why the last section appears not to indent):
def get_calendar_for_currency(currency):
"""Return the appropriate QuantLib calendar based on the currency code."""
if currency == "USD":
    return ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.GovernmentBond)
elif currency == "EUR":
    return ql.TARGET()  # TARGET calendar is often used for EUR
elif currency == "GBP":
    return ql.UnitedKingdom()
elif currency == "SEK":
    return ql.Sweden()
else:
    print(f"Unsupported currency: {currency}")
    return None

def get_interest_rate_curves(currencies, connection_string=CONNECTION_STRING):
"""Generate a dictionary of interest rate curves for each currency."""
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
interest_rate_curves = {}

for currency in currencies:
    # Query to fetch the latest timestamp for the specified currency
    latest_timestamp_query = text(f"""
        SELECT MAX(timestamp) AS latest_timestamp
        FROM fm.tbl_irs_prices
        WHERE ccy = :currency
    """)

    with engine.connect() as connection:
        result = connection.execute(latest_timestamp_query, {"currency": currency})
        latest_timestamp = result.scalar()

    # Query the rates using the latest timestamp
    rates_query = text("""
        SELECT tenor, price
        FROM fm.tbl_irs_prices
        WHERE ccy = :currency AND timestamp = :latest_timestamp
    """)

    with engine.connect() as connection:
        rates_df = pd.read_sql(rates_query, connection, params={"currency": currency, "latest_timestamp": latest_timestamp})

    # Parse tenors and rates
    tenors = [ql.Period(int(t.split()[0]), ql.Years) for t in rates_df['tenor']]
    rates = [r / 100.0 for r in rates_df['price']]  # Convert rates to decimal

    calendar = get_calendar_for_currency(currency)

    # Define other parameters for rate helpers
    convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
    end_of_month = False
    day_count = ql.Actual360()

    # Construct rate helpers for the interest rate curve
    todays_date = ql.Date().todaysDate()
    rate_helpers = [
        ql.DepositRateHelper(
            ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)),
            tenor,           # Use tenor directly as a Period
            2,               # Fixing days
            calendar,
            convention,
            end_of_month,
            day_count
        ) for rate, tenor in zip(rates, tenors)
    ]

    yield_curve = ql.PiecewiseFlatForward(todays_date, rate_helpers, ql.Actual365Fixed())
    interest_rate_curves[currency] = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(yield_curve)
    logging.info(f'{currency} swap curve created from {min(tenors)} to {max(tenors)}.')

return interest_rate_curves

def calculate_spreads_for_dataframe(df, currencies=['EUR', 'USD'], contract_terms=CONTRACT_TERMS, connection_string=CONNECTION_STRING):
# Fetch interest rate curves for all currencies
interest_rate_curves = get_interest_rate_curves(currencies, connection_string)

# Set QuantLib evaluation date
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date().todaysDate()

def calculate_cds_spread_for_row(row, interest_rate_curves=interest_rate_curves, contract_terms=contract_terms):
    """
    Calculate the CDS spread for a given row of data, with detailed debugging information.

    Parameters:
        row (pd.Series): The row of CDS data.
        interest_rate_curves (dict): A dictionary of interest rate curves by currency.
        contract_terms (list): A list of contract term dictionaries.

    Returns:
        float: The calculated CDS spread in basis points or None if any error occurs.
    """
    # Extract row details
    price = row['eod_price']
    tenor = row['tenor']
    contract_currency = row['ccy']

    # Display row details if tenor is invalid
    if not isinstance(tenor, str) or len(tenor) < 2:
        print(f"Invalid tenor format for row: {row}")
        return None

    # Determine calendar based on currency
    calendar = get_calendar_for_currency(contract_currency)
    if not calendar:
        print(f"Unsupported currency: {contract_currency} for row: {row}")
        return None

    # Get the interest rate curve for the contract currency
    interest_rate_curve = interest_rate_curves.get(contract_currency)
    if interest_rate_curve is None:
        print(f"No interest rate curve found for currency {contract_currency} in row: {row}")
        return None

    # Look up the contract terms
    contract = next(
        (item for item in contract_terms if item.get("ccy") == contract_currency), None
    )
    if not contract:
        print(f"No contract terms found for currency {contract_currency} in row: {row}")
        return None

    # Retrieve necessary contract data
    recovery_rate = contract["recovery_rate"]
    coupon_rate = contract["coupon"] / 10000

    # Calculate the implied hazard rate without limiting the price range
    try:
        implied_hazard_rate = -np.log(1 - price / 100) / ql.Actual365Fixed().yearFraction(
            ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate,
            ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate + ql.Period(tenor)
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error calculating hazard rate for row {row}: {e}")
        return None

    # Debug: Output calculated hazard rate
    print(f"Implied hazard rate for row {row}: {implied_hazard_rate}")

    # Create the CDS schedule
    cds_schedule = ql.Schedule(
        ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate,
        ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate + ql.Period(tenor),
        ql.Period("3M"),
        calendar,
        ql.Following,
        ql.Following,
        ql.DateGeneration.Forward,
        False
    )

    # Define the probability curve using the implied hazard rate
    probability_curve = ql.FlatHazardRate(
        0, ql.NullCalendar(), ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(implied_hazard_rate)), ql.Actual365Fixed()
    )
    probability_curve_handle = ql.DefaultProbabilityTermStructureHandle(probability_curve)

    # Define the CDS contract
    cds = ql.CreditDefaultSwap(
        ql.Protection.Seller,
        1000000,  # Notional
        coupon_rate,
        cds_schedule,
        ql.Following,
        ql.Actual360()
    )

    # Use Actual/365Fixed day count for the interest rate curve in the engine
    engine = ql.IsdaCdsEngine(probability_curve_handle, recovery_rate, interest_rate_curve)
    cds.setPricingEngine(engine)

    # Calculate the fair spread
    try:
        spread = cds.fairSpread()
        print(f"Calculated spread for row {row}: {spread}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error calculating spread for row {row}: {e}")
        return None

    return spread * 10000  # Convert to basis points

# Apply the CDS spread calculation to each row
df['calculated_spread'] = df.apply(calculate_cds_spread_for_row, axis=1)
return df

def read_database(connection_string=CONNECTION_STRING):

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

existing_records_query = f"""
                SELECT *
                FROM fm.tbl_cds_prices
                WHERE category not in ('index_option')
            """

# Execute the query and load existing records
df = pd.read_sql(
    existing_records_query,
    con=engine
    )

return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
df = read_database()
df = calculate_spreads_for_dataframe(df)
print(df)

A typical output is as follows:
Calculated spread for row clearing_date                                2024-11-18
issuer_name                            Westpac Bkg Corp
instrument_name     WSTP.SNRFOR.USD.MR14.100.2029-12-20
eod_price                                       103.472
category                                    single_name
contract_name                                      WSTP
tenor                                                5Y
coupon                                            100.0
series                                              NaN
version                                                
maturity_date                                2029-12-20
ccy                                                 USD
restructuring                                      MR14
seniority                                        SNRFOR
recovery_rate                                       0.4
quote_convention                                 spread
timestamp                                           NaT
Name: 12690, dtype: object: nan

As I don't get any errors, it leads me to believe my logic, rather than my syntax is the problem, so presumably there is a stupid error somewhere here, but I haven't been able to spot it.
Is someone able to point me in the correct direction (of course if there is any info I have missed please say)?
Just trying to include the data as per one of the comments.
Swap data (tbl_irs_prices):



swap_price_id
tenor
price
cod
quote_time
quote_date
ccy
timestamp




173
1 Yr
2.51
-0.02
17:42:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


174
2 Yr
2.31
-0.02
17:42:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


175
3 Yr
2.28
-0.02
17:40:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


176
4 Yr
2.28
-0.03
17:40:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


177
5 Yr
2.29
-0.03
17:43:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


178
6 Yr
2.30
-0.04
17:43:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


179
7 Yr
2.31
-0.04
17:41:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


180
8 Yr
2.33
-0.05
17:42:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


181
9 Yr
2.34
-0.06
17:43:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


182
10 Yr
2.36
-0.05
17:43:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


183
12 Yr
2.39
-0.06
17:42:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


184
15 Yr
2.41
-0.06
17:43:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


185
20 Yr
2.35
-0.06
17:40:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


186
30 Yr
2.14
-0.05
17:42:00
08/11/2024
EUR
08/11/2024 16:43


187
1 Yr
4.55
0.03
17:40:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


188
2 Yr
4.33
0.04
17:42:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


189
3 Yr
4.24
0.03
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


190
4 Yr
4.18
0.02
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


191
5 Yr
4.14
0.01
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


192
6 Yr
4.13
0.00
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


193
7 Yr
4.12
-0.01
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


194
8 Yr
4.12
-0.02
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


195
9 Yr
4.12
-0.01
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


196
10 Yr
4.13
-0.01
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


197
12 Yr
4.15
-0.02
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


198
15 Yr
4.17
-0.03
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


199
20 Yr
4.15
-0.03
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


200
25 Yr
4.08
-0.03
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43


201
30 Yr
3.99
-0.03
17:43:00
08/11/2024
USD
08/11/2024 16:43



CDS Data (tbl_cds_prices):



clearing_date
issuer_name
instrument_name
eod_price
category
contract_name
tenor
coupon
series
version
maturity_date
ccy
restructuring
seniority
recovery_rate
quote_convention
timestamp




08/11/2024
Anglo Amern plc
AAUK.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.100.2029-12-20
100.318
single_name
AAUK
5Y
100
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Anglo Amern plc
AAUK.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.25.2029-12-20
96.7288
single_name
AAUK
5Y
25
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Anglo Amern plc
AAUK.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.500.2029-12-20
119.461
single_name
AAUK
5Y
500
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRFOR.EUR.MM.100.2029-12-20
103.069
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
100
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRFOR.EUR.MM.300.2029-12-20
112.769
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
300
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRFOR.EUR.MM.500.2029-12-20
122.469
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
500
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.100.2029-12-20
102.788
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
100
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.300.2029-12-20
112.468
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
300
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.500.2029-12-20
122.148
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
500
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRLAC.EUR.MM14.100.2029-12-20
101.691
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
100
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRLAC
NULL
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRLAC.EUR.MM14.300.2029-12-20
111.31
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
300
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRLAC
NULL
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SNRLAC.EUR.MM14.500.2029-12-20
120.929
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
500
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRLAC
NULL
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Cr Agricole SA
ACAFP.SUBLT2.EUR.MM14.100.2029-12-20
100.027
single_name
ACAFP
5Y
100
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SUBLT2
0.2
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
ACCOR
ACCOR.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.100.2029-12-20
101.551
single_name
ACCOR
5Y
100
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
ACCOR
ACCOR.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.25.2029-12-20
97.9427
single_name
ACCOR
5Y
25
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
ACCOR
ACCOR.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.500.2029-12-20
120.798
single_name
ACCOR
5Y
500
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Adecco Group AG
ADECGRO.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.100.2029-12-20
100.158
single_name
ADECGRO
5Y
100
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11


08/11/2024
Adecco Group AG
ADECGRO.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.25.2029-12-20
96.6548
single_name
ADECGRO
5Y
25
NULL

20/12/2029
EUR
MM14
SNRFOR
0.4
spread
08/11/2024 19:11




have you tried using JPMorgan's open-sourced CDS model? https://cdsmodel.com/ Related question: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44969

I'm not proficient in C++, so I found that code a bit difficult to read, as I use Python / Quantlib for everything else, this is my preferred option.
Also, from my understanding, my approach should work, which leads me to believe I have a logic error, rather than a completely invalid approach.

someone might be more likely to help you debug your code example if you trim it down to be self-contained instead of getting data from a source no one else has.

Ah, the data is freely available on the ICE site here:
https://www.ice.com/cds-settlement-prices/icc/single-name-instruments
All I did was tidy it up, so for example, ICE will have a contract name as follows:
AAUK.SNRFOR.EUR.MM14.100.2029-12-20
That gives us:
Issuer Name, Seniority, Currency, Restructuring, Coupon & Maturity.
But I can equally upload a csv of the tables I have if that would help (is that possible here)?

but where do you get the interest rate curve, for example? You need one, although it has little effect.

Ah sorry, yes that is a good point, I see what you mean, have added the two tables in.
